# Is it a security vulnerability for the server to use Java serialization over the network?

Tags: java, security, serialization

I am creating a multiplayer game with a server, and using serialized objects to send messages back and forth between it and the client programs. Here is an MCVE of my communication code:

```
loop: while(true)
    try {
        Thread.yield();
        Object raw = in.readObject();
        NTask task = (NTask) raw;
        processRequest(task);
    } catch (IOException e){
        break loop;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new SecurityWarning("Client is sending erroneous messages. Possible security breach.", raw);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where `NTask` is a superclass for a bunch of different message types and `processTask` decides what to do with each object based on the type.

My question is whether this poses a security vulnerability for my server. Can someone write their own code that sends an object to my server that will cause harm, and have it execute its malicious code before a ClassCastException is thrown on line 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user sends the server an object of a class that the server doesn't have in its classpath, the server won't be able to load this class, and thus won't be able to instantiate the object received.

What a user could do though is send an object of a class that the server knows, but which doesn't respect the invariants of the class (for example, send you a task with a null name although that should never happen with a regular user).

Serializing an object basically consists in sending the class name of the object, and its state (i.e. the value of all its fields). The byte-code of the class (i.e. the behavior) is not sent. It's loaded from the local classpath.

Comment: What do you mean by a task with a null name? I'm assuming for this question that `NTask`s will sanitize their input, therefore any `NTask` object is safe. What I'm worried about is other objects that might run code as they are deserialized.

Comment: Let's suppose NTask has a field `name` that should never be null. A malicious user could send you an NTask instance that has a null name.